# What is the best, free, subversion control repository that can be used with the Eclipse subversion plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, version-control

For my software engineering class project, my group and I are developing and Android application. We have decided the best way to keep the code managed is via the subversion control plugin for Eclipse. However, none of us have actually managed our own repository. We have always been given it from our professors. Where can I find a free repository to upload our code? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are tons of places that offer free repositories. Here are few:

- https://www.assembla.com/subversion/
- http://www.projectlocker.com/
- http://riouxsvn.com/
- http://beanstalkapp.com/

Comment: Assembla looks pretty good. So after I create my repository and download the plugin for Eclipse, I simply type in the repository's URL, and I am good to go (I am the only one in my group who has never been exposed to SVN before)?

Comment: Yes, once you create the repository, Assembla will give you a link, or you copy down the link yourself and then paste it into subversion plugin when it asks for it

Comment: After I installed the Eclipse plugin and set up a repository on Assembla, I attempted to upload an existing project to test it out. This is the error message I receive: "Unable to load default SVN Client." What is wrong? I remember reading something about "connectors" but couldn't find where or how to download them.

Comment: @JTWheeler - If you used the Subversive plugin - this pages explains about SVN connectors:  http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php

Comment: Assembla, ProjectLocker, Beanstalk not free as of July 2015. RiouxSVN limited to 20MB.

Comment: @AlanB What I see (October 2015) is that Assembla offers unlimited users, unlimited repositories, 1 GB for free, and RiouxSVN gives you four 50 MB repositories for free.

Comment: Ha thanks they've changed it then.

Comment: Most of them are paid but good list

Comment: GitLab is not SVN-based. It's Git-based.

Answer (score 5):

I would definitely recommend Assembla. The first time I used it I was in a similar situation as you. Didn't know what to choose, overwhelmed by all the choices. I went with Assembla and having used Assembla extensively since, I'm quite sure it will satisfy your needs. Has great features for team working also, and being robust, free and easy to manage it's worth a try.

Comment: It's not free anymore (July 2015)

Comment: It's not free anymore (March 2017)